# How can I use NSRunningApplication to see running applications in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in swift , and I'd like to see running application in the device or extract different information from the device like how many times the application was used ...

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work for you or get you close to what you want.

```
for runningApp in NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications as! [NSRunningApplication] {
    if let bundleIdentifier = runningApp.bundleIdentifier {
        NSLog(bundleIdentifier)
    }

    if let launchDate = runningApp.launchDate {
        NSLog(launchDate.description)
    }
}
```