# ReplayKit - Is it possible to get the name of app in use while screen sharing?

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

In an app that allows screen sharing among multiple users, I would like to implement a certain process only when the screen sharer is using a specific app (e.g. Instagram).

In order to implement the above feature, I would like to know if there is a way in iOS to get information on what app is on screen while screen sharing.

Does the iOS SDK provide a function to retrieve the name of the app on screen while screen sharing with ReplayKit?

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387728/how-can-i-use-nsrunningapplication-to-see-running-applications-in-swift

Comment: "NSWorkspace" seems to be a macOS class, not for iOS...